# Is there an easy way to copy a TableForm column and convert it into a vector?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, vector, list-manipulation

Is there an easy way to take a column output from a TableForm command, like this:

```
6.3121375196805859436
6.9003005747830988641
8.9768182443850834342
8.9138378561826490430
7.9892637649923361149
5.7310834764460301485
7.8127176986072821866
7.2290808062999679496
7.4923081278967455513
```

And convert it back into a "Table" or "List" or "Vector", i.e.,

```
    {6.3121375196805859436,6.9003005747830988641,8.9768182443850834342,8.9138378561826490430,7.9892637649923361149,5.7310834764460301485,7.8127176986072821866,7.2290808062999679496,7.4923081278967455513}
```

It is not so hard to do manually if there are only a dozen items, but when there are hundreds, it gets a bit tedious. What I've been doing is copy as "plain text", paste into Microsoft Word, replace "paragraph" marks with commas (Find ^p; Replace ,), put in the curly brackets, and copy it back into Mathematica. Surely there is an easier way?

Well, here is one way, and recall that I want to just translate within Mathematica itself:

```
StringReplace["{0.27053645617075607328
0.29665173751384943109
0.25127005359909123280
0.23465443792124858652
0.25447200323727824111
0.26802978565269905254
0.26622025533442188507
0.31359242691527905846
0.26810428054117807246
0.29408129579900499019
0.29001875144558125364
0.24823119448471783028
0.27626029400322289905
0.27347835282168678727
0.26924305884480351606
0.25995335230286428315
0.25585822835794553252
0.26573081058995874804
0.28819488915098074127
0.27186805052334818319
0.31654336155657666993}", "\n" -> ","]
```

That is, copy it as text, and paste it into the command

```
StringReplace["{paste here}", "\n" -> ","]
```

The output is then formatted correctly. I would have thought it would be a builtin command, and well, sort of, it is. Anyone else have an answer, please?

Comment: `but when there are hundreds, it gets a bit tedious. What I've been doing is copy as "plain text", paste into Microsoft Word` you are making things so hard for yourself. Simply use Latex. Mathematica has great Latex export. You can export the data from your table in Mathematica to Latex using TeXForm and include the output back to your latex document. Word is not the right tool for engineering, science and math reports.  I use Latex for everything.

Comment: Don't follow that. I copied via LaTeX, and pasted in a .txt file it gave:\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 0.99914480523366600774343767837101128030306037301171630246007280113 \\
0.99886229380227662563491290721686478149534907102631923379939140936 \\
 0.99912233712195990056006452559240871933654682894782657439809033693 \\
 0.99949936790492257234374456221274757414510894431488309820117792698 \\
 0.99915451603281797293363463509619228642538870957763819953196258552 \\
\end{array}
\right)

Comment: Can you copy the table to an input cell and then set a variable to equal it, then look at the FullForm of the variable, and then operate on that?

Comment: @berniethejet Sort of. But that gave me an idea that worked. Namely an adaptation of your comment and Chris Degnen's answer, see the comment below his post.

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`TableForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html) should only be used for display. Assign a name to the **input** to `TableForm` and take the column that you want from the input.

```
SeedRandom[1234];

(mat = RandomReal[1, {9, 3}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

For the second column

```
mat[[All, 2]]

{* {0.521964, 0.0116446, 0.479332, 0.984993, 0.884729, 0.91956, 0.587943, \
0.696159, 0.632741} *}
```

Or, for the first column

```
mat[[All, 1]]

(* {0.876608, 0.377913, 0.543757, 0.759896, 0.459017, 0.263973, 0.98729, \
0.790215, 0.401549} *)
```

Comment: Fair enough, but when the current context is dumped, all one may have is the printout of the table left of the original calculation, and if that takes 24 h to calculate, one would have the problem of translating a table into a vector whose origin is difficult to resurrect, in order to use it for further processing. That is the context I am most interested in. It is fine to say shouldn't, but without saving the context, what you suggest is not typically useful in my circumstance. In turn, saving the context is a bit tedious, I have done so in the past, but it is not time deployment efficient.

Comment: On the other hand, what is displayed in a table is actually stored at full precision, just not shown as such, so that a generic "copy," followed by generic "paste" into a blank area then wrapped in a Flatten[...] command, which when executed will resurrect the full precision vector from a Table column as shown by following @ChrisDegnen's suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Using sample data

```
TableForm[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 3}]]
```

Select middle column, Copy & Paste.

Add `;` (optional), and evaluate, followed by

```
a = Flatten@%
```

This should set the middle column to `a` with the original precision.

Comment: What's wrong with `% // InputForm`

Comment: @chris Can do that, but the output is not then a vector.

Comment: I like it. I don't like using the semicolon because that converts the output into machine precision. Without it, the Flatten command does not process, but at least it does translate at full precision within that command, so that it can then be copied and pasted correctly, at least sometimes. Can you do something to prevent the automatic conversion to machine precision; it is somewhat inconstant?

Comment: What I can do, is "copy" without choosing a copy format, i.e., just copy. Then paste that, wrap in Flatten[...] and run that. It then resurrects the original precision, which in my case is longer than the 20 significant figures I usually display, and does so as a vector! BTW (+1).

Comment: @Carl Yes, that works well. Copy As > Plain Text is good for Excel but not necessary here.

Comment: Would you consider updating your answer to incorporate the generic "copy" generic "paste" into blank area, wrap in Flatten answer so I can accept your answer. It is the best other suggestion yet.

Answer (score 2):

> <...> when the current context is dumped, all one may have is the printout of the table left of the original calculation, and if that takes 24 h to calculate, one would have the problem of translating a table into a vector whose origin is difficult to resurrect, in order to use it for further processing. That is the context I am most interested in.

If you have an output cell with `TableForm` output, you can create under it an input cell with the following code which will extract the contents of the `TableForm` from the output cell and assign it to a variable `table`:

```
table = First@
  Cases[NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]], 
   grid : TagBox[GridBox[__], _] :> ToExpression@grid, -1]
```

Here is how it can be used:

[image: screenshot]

---

Another method is to right-click on the output cell bracket and select `Convert To` > `InputForm`. The result will look as follows:

[image: screenshot]

Now you can easily select the contents of the recovered original `TableForm` input by double-clicking on the first curly bracket in the  `TableForm` expression, after what you can simply copy the input matrix:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes, that works, but it answers a question I didn't ask, namely how to reformat an entire table, whereas I might only want one or two vectors. (+1), anyway, at least it works.

Comment: @carl Side note: the shortcut for **Convert to**->**InputForm** is Ctrl+Shift+I (in Windows). For more info you may search _shortcut_ in the document.

Comment: @Carl Strictly speaking, as the second method I propose a conversion to `InputForm` rather than reformatting. You always can create a copy of the original table before the conversion. The first method allows to copy the table, you can use `CopyToClipboard` to automate it.

Comment: Well, command+shift+I (Mac) on part of a table got me {
   {NumberForm[
   13.7954506582797826869128070985460977131329506391598692631535901910\
5711700089517$\`$63.29951679410639, 20]}, 
   {NumberForm[
   9.51723244808496444842171494285858490371772785926750641413562067013\
827626151444$\`$62.895016813692926, 20]}, 
   {NumberForm[
   6.05884360398624400908459908131841674266268428965725478730986628166\
706954188622$\`$62.17672870969089, 20]}, 
   {NumberForm[
   9.96452005976523317741573978711645175548238211267411655738745691084\
284653990601$\`$62.02845034867765, 20]}}

Comment: Con't If I run that (shift+return) I get {{8.7114057567481581358},{6.3432511520078327174},{5.8909344004427558882},{13.795450658279782687},{9.5172324480849644484},{6.0588436039862440091},{9.9645200597652331774}}, which brings me back to Flatten[whatever] to reconstruct it as a vector.

Comment: @Carl You didn't say that you use `NumberForm`. But it's not a problem: just apply `/. NumberForm -> (# &)` (paste it right after your matrix and evaluate).

Comment: OK, to copy more than one adjacent vector in a table, do a generic "copy", and generic "paste" into a blank area to get columns, then wrap that in NumberForm[columns,20] and execute, and it will format correctly.

Comment: Humm, great minds think alike, I guess, we said the same thing, but you were 1 minute faster than me.

Comment: Yes, I use NumberForm because I am developing new nonconvex functions as regression models for drug kinetics, and I need 20 significant figures in the output as model parameters following regression, which means that I need sometimes horrendously increased precision for intermediate steps. Anyway, you helped, thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the column with `arrayName[[3]]` or `arrayName[[;;,3]]` (if it is column three; the `;;` is `Span` and captures all of that dimension) and export it to a file with `Export[pathAndName.xlsx,arrayname[[`appropriate designation`]]` to open it in Excel and copy from there.

Comment: That doesn't help. I can just "copy as" choice "plain text" and paste into Excel. However, Excel only stores 20 significant figures, and when copying it, if only copies what is visible, which might be only 3 significant figures. Word works better as a work around because it doesn't interpret the characters pasted into it.